# Angular route not routing to the component

Tags: angular

I am struggling to get my route to work. I am using RouterLink which does not navigate to the route. My app.routing has

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/',
  pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
   path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    loadChildren: () => import('./views/main/main.module').then( m => m.MainModule )
  }
];
```

The mainModule has the following

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
 path: 'search',
 component: SearchFormComponent,
 loadChildren: () => import('../../views/search/search.module').then( m => m.SearchModule )
},
{
 path: '**',
 redirectTo: '/home',
 pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
```

The mainModule declares and exports LayoutComponent

In LayoutComponent.html

```
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="'/search'">
      Search
    </a>
```

But when I click on the search in the UI, the route is not going to the search component. It stays on the Home component. Please help - where am I going wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 8 router not redirecting to routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545539/angular-8-router-not-redirecting-to-routes)

Comment: No. Ordering routes is not a problem. I just have two routes. Why is the 'search' route not found

Comment: Your first route is `path: ''` and your second route is `path: 'search'`, Angular router is finding your first path and not going to search.

Comment: @Malcor How can it find '' route when my routerLink has '/serach'? Anyway I tried putting '' route to the end and I still have the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Swap the order of your routes.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
 path: 'search',
 component: SearchFormComponent,
 loadChildren: () => import('../../views/search/search.module').then( m => m.SearchModule )
},
 {
  path: '',
  redirectTo: '/home',
  pathMatch: 'full'
},
{
 path: '**',
 redirectTo: '/home',
 pathMatch: 'full'
}
];
```

Angular router works with first come, first served.

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. In the configuration above, routes with a static path are listed first, followed by an empty path route, that matches the default route. The wildcard route comes last because it matches every URL and should be selected only if no other routes are matched first.

From angular website [here](https://angular.io/guide/router)

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545539/angular-8-router-not-redirecting-to-routes)

Update: Although it would still be an issue, so I'll leave the original answer here. Try setting your router link to

```
   <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['search']">
      Search
    </a>
```

Comment: Unfortunately does not work since my routerLink has '/search'

Comment: Any error messages in the console when clicking the link?

Comment: No error message in the console

Comment: I've updated my answer

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately no luck

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved it by removing '' and ** and replacing them with

```
{
 path: '',
 component: HomeComponent,
},
```